# Is SPRibbon TrimById working in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: ribbon

I wrote below code to remove edit and checkout buttons from the ribbon in a publishing page. Although the ribbon.TrimById line is hit while debugging, ribbon buttons are still visible and clickable after that call.

```
SPRibbon ribbon = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this.Page);
if (ribbon != null)
{
    ribbon.TrimById("Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.EditAndCheckout");
}
```

Has anyone experienced this case?

Answer (score 1):

TrimById is working in SharePoint 2013. I've checked maybe you've got the ID wrong, but it seems it's fine. You can get all IDs from here: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\CMDUI.XML

I would suggest to try removing ribbon buttons instead of the whole group and maybe use another approach with custom actions:

`<CustomAction Id="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.EditAndCheckout.Hidden"Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
      <CommandUIExtension>
        <CommandUIDefinitions>
          <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.EditAndCheckout" />
        </CommandUIDefinitions>
      </CommandUIExtension>
    </CustomAction>`

Comment: Paul thanks, I actually copied ribbon location from the cmdui.xml. I also created a webpart which includes a textbox and button. I can enter desired ribbon location to this textbox and trim this location on button click. I tried removing buttons instead of groups, but it still does not work.